# Result of install MediaWiki is messed up

Tags: cpanel, mediawiki, mediawiki-installation

I have this problem. I don't know how to describe this problem after install MediaWiki over Installatron Applications Browser in CPanel.

Version: 1.36.0

I see this page after install MediaWiki. I can't find the perfect page. there is no design now.

How can I fix this problem? Is there any solution? Thank you for your advice from now :)

[image]

Comment: What is the path to that page? It looks like you opened a binary file.

Comment: every page like this. I don't know why happening like this. Old versions not like that. This version like the screenshot. Cpanel giving me 1.36version.